# Массивы в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь из массива передать объекты в instantiate, вроде все написано корректно ошибок при запуске нет, но и ожидаемого результата тоже подскажите почему?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mapGenirator : MonoBehaviour 
{         
    public enum ListBlock
    {
        Mpole1,
        Mpole2
    }

    public Transform SB_Mpole1;
    public Transform SB_Mpole2;
    public Transform ground;

    Transform ReturnList (ListBlock RL)
    {
        switch (RL)
        {
            case ListBlock.Mpole1:
                return SB_Mpole1;

            case ListBlock.Mpole2:
                return SB_Mpole2;

            default:
                return SB_Mpole1;
        }
    }

    ListBlock [,] ArrayListBlock;

    void createlevel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                float PositionBlock_x = transform.position.x + SB_Mpole1.localScale.x;
                float PositionBlock_z = transform.position.z + SB_Mpole1.localScale.z;
                float PositionBlock_y = transform.position.y + 10f;

                Transform AddArrey = ReturnList( ArrayListBlock[i, j]);
                Transform createBlock = (Transform)Instantiate(SB_Mpole1, new Vector3(PositionBlock_x, PositionBlock_y, PositionBlock_z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }

    void fullArrey ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                 ArrayListBlock[i,j] = ListBlock.Mpole1;
            }
        }       
    }

    void Sharing()
    {
        fullArrey();
        createlevel();
    }

    void start ()
    {
        createlevel();
        ArrayListBlock = new ListBlock[10,10];
    }        
}
```

Comment: Ожидаемого результат нету -- это, конечно, серьёзное описание проблемы.

Оттрасируйте все функции, выясните, приходят ли в них ожидаемые вами аргументы и выдают ли они ожидаемые вами значения. Когда каждая ваша функция будет вести себя ожидаемым вами образом, тогда и вся программа будет.

Comment: ОФФТОП: мне одному кажется, что? если у каждых фигурных скобок? первую поднять наверх к объявлению метода/класса/etc, то запись будет чуть короче и не сильно повредит codestyle?

Comment: > если у каждых фигурных скобок? первую поднять наверх к объявлению метода/класса/etc, то запись будет чуть короче и не сильно повредит codestyle?

У вас таких есть целая секта, так что не одному. И это, между прочим, один из ключевых аспектов стиля кодирования.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал все немного не так.

Создал бы массив объектов

```
public Transform[] prefabs;
```

А дальше бы инстанцинировал его

```
Instantiate(prefabs[Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length)], new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

Сейчас будет рандомно инстанционироватьсяо объект из массиваю

На заметку [работа с Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) в юнитях. Проблема в чем я не понял, но суть вроде как уловил, мой вариант такой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас `start()` с маленькой буквы "s". Это опечатка? Если так и задумано, то ваш код просто не вызывается.

Чтобы метод вызывался движком, необходимо имплеминтировать  метод [`MonoBehaviour.Start()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html):

```
void Start ()
    {
        createlevel();
        ArrayListBlock = new ListBlock[10,10];
    }
```

Comment: @Дмитрий еще немного логики )

Comment: @NickVolynkin редактировали всем миром. Теперь всё предельно логично. :)

Comment: В данном случае не нужно делать никакой override. Вы сами показали код без перегрузки метода и это правильно. Но ответ сформулирован не правильно.
Unity использует систему сообщений для вызова этих методов.